# How to validate ckeditor field using laravel-jsvalidation library?

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Library: https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation

This library is awesome, validating form fields with ease but it is not validating ckeditor filed, can you plz guide me what to do?